# Monitor Angular component lifecycle hooks

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular it is possible to monitor the Router for routing events ([see docu](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)).

Is a similiar concept possible for components lifecycle hooks([see docu](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks))?

Basically I'd like to achieve a kind of tracing for components within an Angular application. Routing events are easy to trace, but not all components lifecycle events are based on routing.

I'd like to avoid the "manual" implementation / duplication within each's component `ngOnInit()` or `onDestroy()` `etc` method. E.g.

```
export class MyAwesomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor (private someTraceImplementation) {}

   public onOnit():void {
      someTraceImplementation.trace('init', 'MyAwesomeComponent');
   }

   publicc onDestroy() {
      someTraceImplementation.trace('destroy', 'MyAwesomeComponent');
   }
}

export class LessAwesomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor (private someTraceImplementation) {}

   public onOnit():void {
      someTraceImplementation.trace('init', 'LessAwesomeComponent');
   }

   publicc onDestroy(): void {
      someTraceImplementation.trace('destroy', 'LessAwesomeComponent');
   }
}
```

Externalizing the tracing into an implementation of a base class

```
export class TracingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   public onOnit():void {
      someTraceImplementation.trace('init', 'LessAwesomeComponent');
   }

   public onDestroy(): void {
      someTraceImplementation.trace('destroy', 'LessAwesomeComponent');
   }
}
```

does not help, since `MyAwesomeComponent` and `LessAwesomeComponent` will overwrite the `onInit` / `onDestroy` methods.

Can a more general / module based approch be done?